# найти номер четверти, в которой находится максимальный элемент

Tags: java

> Дана квадратная матрица A порядка M, которая делится на четыре части
>   главной и дополнительной диагоналями. Требуется найти номер четверти,
>   в которой находится максимальный элемент того же знака, что и сумма
>   всех элементов диагоналей.

У  меня  получилось следующее: я  смог сделать двумерный  массив  и заполнить  его рандомными  числами. Нашел  сумму  главной  и дополнительной  диагоналей. 
Вопрос: как  мне  найти номер  четверти с  максимальным  элементом?
Буду  очень благодарен  за помощь.
Вот  мой  код:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Task {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 5;          
        int [][] a = new int [m][m];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            //сумма  диагоналей
            int sum1 = 0;
            int sum2 = 0;
            for ( i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                sum1 += a[i][i];
                sum2 += a[i][m-1-i];
            }
            System.out.println(sum1);
            System.out.println(sum2);
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Без учета знака, для простоты.

```
int max = 0;
int quater = 0;
for(x = 0; x < m; x++){
    for(y = 0; y < m; y++){
        if(max < a[x][y] && x != y && x != m-y-1){
            max=a[x][y];
            if(x > y && x > m-y-1){
                quater = 1;
            } else if (x > y && x < m-y-1){
                quater = 2;
            } else if (x < y && x < m-y-1){
                quater = 3;
            } else {
                quater = 4;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо  Вам  большое!

Comment: спасибо слева от ответа ;)

Comment: Хорошо теперь буду  знать))))